# Perl add a pair of tags to the beginning and the end of file

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

I use the following `Perl` code in order to add `<root>` and `</root>` to the first line and the last line in the file respectively,

```
s/^/<root>/ if $.==1;
s/$/<\/root>/ if eof;
```

which gives this error:
`Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)` for the second substitution.

But strangely this could work in the command line:

`perl -p -i -e 'eof && s/$/<\/root>/; s/^/<root>/ if $.==1;' 1.txt`

Comment: How do you read the file? Your code must be in a while loop that is done by `-p` option in one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine with perl 5.26.1, if I set it up like this:

```
use strict;
open my $fh, '<', 'test.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    s/^/<root>/ if $.==1;
    s/$/<\/root>/ if eof;
    print $_;
}
```

Assuming `test.txt` only contains a single line

```
test123
```

...the output is:

```
<root>test123</root>
```

This should be what is expected? I can only assume there's some shenanigans going on in other parts of the code which you haven't posted?